# Ansible combine arrays in dict

Tags: ansible

I've got dict with array like this

```
tests:
  test01:
    state: 'enabled'
    objects: 
      - 'A111'
      - 'B111'
  test02:
    state: 'enabled'
    objects:
      - 'C222'
      - 'D222'
  test03:
    state: 'enabled'
    objects:
      - 'E333'
      - 'F333'
```

How to combine array "objects" together in one output? The result should be

```
"msg": "A111,B111,E333,F333,C222,D222"
```

Comment: it may really be worth reading this page, https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8 this talks about all tge ways to modify variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is multiliner but without hardcoding of items

```
- set_fact:
    tests_dict: "{{ item }}"
  with_dict: "{{ tests }}"
  register: tests_items

- set_fact:
    tests_objects: "{{ tests_objects }} + {{ item.item.value.objects }}"
  with_items: "{{ tests_items.results }}"
  vars:
    tests_objects: []

- debug:
    msg: "{{ tests_objects | join(',') }}"
```

> ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
>       "msg": "C222,D222,E333,F333,A111,B111" }

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need

```
  - debug:
     msg: "{{(tests.test01.objects,tests.test02.objects,tests.test03.objects)|flatten|join('\n')|replace('\n', ',')}}"
```

> ok: [localhost] => {
>       "msg": "A111,B111,C222,D222,E333,F333"
>   }

Comment: Not really. Your answer is array but I need string. And what if there will be more tests like test04...testN?